# open Facebook app iphone 5 doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

i'm using this code for open facebook app to go in my profile. With iphone 4 this works correctly but with iphone 5 it opens another app.
i don't understand what is the problem.
the version of ios and facebook app are the same

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/myprofile_id"]]
```